# Error when running build as native Sencha

Tags: iphone, ios, extjs, sencha-2

```
Mac-mini-2:sink eit$ sencha app build native

[INFO] Deploying your application to /path/to/www/sink/build/package
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Copied resources/icons
[INFO] Copied resources/loading
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies...
[INFO] Found 139 dependencies. Concatenating all into app.js...
[INFO] Processed sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minifying sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Processed app.js
[INFO] Minifying app.js
[INFO] Minifying resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Minified sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minified app.js
[INFO] Minified resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Generated app.json
[INFO] Embedded microloader into index.html
[INFO] Packaging your application as a native app...
[INFO] The application was successfully packaged
Failed to execute system command while signing application with error 256
Failed to package application
[ERROR] codesign_allocate: for architecture armv7 object: /path/to/www/sink/build/native//Sencha Touch 2 Packaging.app/stbuild_template malformed object (unknown load command 8)
/path/to/www/sink/build/native//Sencha Touch 2 Packaging.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
```

How can I fix the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I included the certificate file name in the certificatePath & didn't include 'certificatePassword' directive.

I hope this helps, but I'm fairly new to all this & fumbling around through various problems I'm having.